# Is the following set (with the usual addition and multiplication of numbers) a field?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory

Is the follwing set a field?

$Q ∪ [-1,1]$

I read the notes in my textbook about fields and understand most of the field axioms. However I want to see an example which is worked. Furthermore I am confused whether a field HAS to HAVE $0$ and $1$ in it?

So for this question I am leaning towards saying it is a field, as I cannot find a pair of numbers that violates the axioms. However would I prove it formally... or am I wrong and is this not a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a field, because it's not closed under addition. $100$ and $1/\sqrt{2}$ belong to your set, but $100 + 1/\sqrt{2}$ doesn't.

Yes, this set has an additive identity $0$ and a multiplicative identity $1$, because you are adding and multiplying numbers in the usual manner, but that doesn't matter much because the set is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $\pi$ as a product of two set elements to establish a contradiction. (I.e. to show it is not a field, because it is not closed under multiplication.)

As to your question re whether a field has to have $0$ and $1$ in it, the answer is yes (sort of). It has to have *a* zero and *a* $1$, but they don't have to be the zero and the one from the set of real numbers. For instance, the meromorphic functions on the complex plane form a field; however, here 0 and 1 are replaced with the constant functions 0 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Note that in order for $\mathbb{Q}\cup [-1,1]$ to be a field, using the operations inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, its $0$ and $1$ *would* have to be the real numbers $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: @Brad That is not the question that OP asked, though.

Comment: @EricAuld I guess it does make sense since $pi$ is irrational and therefore not in the set, however I am still unsure on how to write it as a product of two rational numbers.

Comment: @Mac: Try to divide it by a big integer.

Comment: @Mac - it's not the product of two rational numbers, but it is the product of some rational number and some real number in the set $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith I've tried and I still can't understand intuitively how I can get a irrational number from the above..

Comment: @mac Is there a rational multiple of $\pi$ in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @Mac - nik, Eric Auld and I are all thinking the same thing here...